# Will Jenkins show the changes that happened in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I have setup my bitbucket with Jenkins and it's running perfectly. When I change and push the code to bitbucket, Jenkins runs automatically, but my question is: Is there any option to show what change has been made by users, for instance when lines are added/removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the git plugins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

this one might help you:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin